# Exposed form in block not found in block view drupal 7

Tags: views, blocks

I am facing an issue what I need is expose some fields for search criteria & put these search boxes/drop downs to my sidebar, I didn't find the option "expose from in block" in the Exposed Form section, I have a block view, It is showing on the view page but not on the block view why?

[image: see the snapshot below.]

Is there any solution regarding?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Views Block Exposed Filter Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block) module.

Views normally restricts exposed form blocks to page displays. So if you want an exposed form for a block display you either have to go with this module or you build your own block in code and embed the exposed form there.

Comment: Thankyou very very much berliner, its working :) It would be really great if I found you earlier. bundle of thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ;) That's why we have this site here!

Comment: Its really helpful site for all the problem holders. ;)